# nhibernate disable unicode

Tags: nhibernate, unicode, unicode-string

in our company we are using nhibernate as our default mapper. I write queries using nhibernate criteria - I noticed that all parameters are send as unicode like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT this_.ID as ID23_0_, this_.Nazwa as Nazwa23_0_, this_.Opis as Opis23_0_, this_.TypGrupy as TypGrupy23_0_, this_.CzyDystrybuowana as CzyDystr5_23_0_, this_.CzyAktywna as CzyAktywna23_0_ FROM Grupa this_ WHERE this_.Nazwa like @p0',N'@p0 nvarchar(50)',@p0=N'%something%'
```

This is not the desired behavior. Is it possible to disable unicode in nhibernate queries?
Thanks

Romek

Comment: Why? Are you intentionally restricting your software to the English speaking market? The field names suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to match the mapping files to use Ansi String instead of Unicode whcih is probably the default value.

Check [this](http://NHibernatePropertyTypes.) mapping table between Database and Nhibernate, and the sections between 5.2.2 and 5.4 on [Nhibernate - the Basic O/R Mapping](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping#), notice the type attribute i guess you can explicit define ANSIString in there.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the type in the mapping file from System.String to AnsiString and now the generated query doesn't contain N' :-)